# iOS 9 (on iPad only): UIWebView does not show select option elements anymore

Tags: select, webview, uiwebview, ios9

If this dropdown is loaded in a WebView it only shows the select-element. By clicking on the box nothing happens. If there is an "click"-eventlistener to this box, calling an alert, it shows this alert and after clicking the alert away the list shows up. It looks like the list is hidden by the WebView. Please help!

```
<select type="selector" class="selector" id="systemSelector" style="top: 30px;">
    <option value="0">Value</option>
    <option value="1">Value</option>
    <option value="2">Value</option>
    <option value="3">Value</option>
    <option value="4">Value</option>
    <option value="5">Value</option>
</select>
```

And if there are inputs field, by clicking in an input fields, it shows the keyboard. Right after the keyboard shows up by clicking on the select box, all options are shown as well.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Yes, this issue can be resolved by getting rid of the workaround code for iOS8 when it comes to pop-up windows. Obviously in iOS8 was a problem with pop-up windows, therefore we implemented a delegate method in order to handle pop-up windows in iOS8. This code led to the current issue in iOS9, not showing dropdown menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution looks in my code like this:

At top of the .m-file you put:

```
#define IS_IOS8_3_AND_LOWER (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_8_3)
```

In @implementation you put:

```
#if IF_IS_IOS8_3_AND_LOWER
/* Workaround for Apple bug (UIPopoverPresentationController ... should have a non-nil sourceView ...). */
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion {
        // Load resources for iOS 8.3 or earlier
        if ([viewControllerToPresent respondsToSelector:@selector(popoverPresentationController)]) {
            if (viewControllerToPresent.popoverPresentationController && !viewControllerToPresent.popoverPresentationController.sourceView) {
                return;
            }
        }
        [super presentViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:flag completion:completion];
}
#endif
```

Comment: When does presentViewController method gets called? I am facing exactly same problem where it is working for alert box..